# How Chromedriver is communicating internally with the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to understand how chromedriver.exe is communicating with Chrome browser internally. What kind of communication channel and protocol is used for such purpose.

I was looking for some architecture diagrams and high level description, but could not found one.

Is it possible to communicate directly with the browser (for automation purposes) without having chromedriver.exe as a proxy ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this [answer from the Chrome Driver users group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/chromedriver-users/xVMy5OGLcl8/2JljtZ1FAAAJ) which includes a high level description of how chromedriver.exe communicates with the Chrome browser.

"[...] ChromeDriver implements the WebDriver protocol, which is a REST-like interface [...]. WebDriver clients communicate with ChromeDriver by sending HTTP requests. ChromeDriver then communicates with the browser through the DevTools remote debugging interface, which is a WebSockets interface [...]."

It is possible to communicate directly with the Chrome browser using the [Chrome DevTools Interface](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) however if not using WebDriver and Selenium it may require a significant amount of work to use this interface for automation purposes.